# Getting Image from drawable and adding to PDF using iText

Tags: android, pdf, itext, drawable

I want to add image to android PDF using iText. I want to achieve this without saving image to SDCard first. I put my image into res/drawable folder but proving the image path doesn’t work and it throws FileNotFound Exception. My path is like this:

```
String path = “res/drawable/myImage.png”
Image image = Image.getInstance(path);
document.add(image);
```

Now please suggest me a solution how I will add correct file path to getInstance(…) method. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Of course it'll not work at that way.

move your image to assets folder to access it with getassets() method

```
// load image
    try {
            // get input stream
           InputStream ims = getAssets().open("myImage.png");
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
           Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
           document.add(image);
        }
   catch(IOException ex)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I cant add bitmap to document add method, do not support of type bitmap :(

Comment: Resources should be preferred over assets,

Comment: Can I use static height and width to image which is going to display on pdf?

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem and now my code works fine :)

Comment: Working Great! Any one know how to remove this added image from PDF file???

Answer (score 20):

I found a solution for your issue. If you want to get image from your drawable folder and put it into a PDF file using iText use this code:

```
try {
    document.open();
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
    BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
    Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();  
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    document.add(image);    
    document.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Working Great! Awesome.

Comment: Working like a Charm !!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to add image to PDF using iText, if the image is dynamic (i.e), if the image cannot be added to asset folder at compile time,

```
public void addImage(Document document,ImageView ivPhoto) throws DocumentException {
try {
     BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivPhoto.getDrawable();       
     Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

     ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);                             
     byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
     Image image = Image.getInstance(imageInByte);
     document.add(image);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, To set Image on particular position 
   move your image to assets folder to get image by getassets() method.
   Hope this will help you!

```
   try {

        InputStream ims = getAssets().open("header1.png");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        image.setAbsolutePosition(10f,750f);
        image.scaleToFit(850,78);
        document.add(image);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("input file uri");
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(in);
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("output file uri"));
    PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getOverContent(1);
   Image deliverImg = Image.getInstance("image URI");
   deliverImg.setAbsolutePosition(420f, 100f);
   content.addImage(deliverImg);
   pdfStamper.close();
} catch (DocumentException de) {
   Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
} catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
}
```