# how to get full image path via image picker android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext

I am selecting a image  from gallery and trying to covert it into pdf using itext , but  when i selecting the image its app crashes  with null pointer excetion
[image] when i logged the picture path getting null( String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);)

code for the same

```
 final  private  int  SELECT_PICTURE = 201;

   select_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        switch(requestCode){

            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
```

error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=201, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:87703 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.pdfcreator/com.example.pdfcreator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4465)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.pdfcreator.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:159)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7590)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:441
```

Comment: How you opened image picker?

Comment: Please add the code of that where you started your activity for result.

Comment: yes I m opening image picker on a button click (code added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved Intent.ACTION_PICK solved  my issue.

i was using this answer [How to convert images to pdf using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438067/how-to-convert-images-to-pdf-using-itext/73030991#73030991) , as he used action ACTION_GET_CONTENT

can any one tell me why ACTION_GET_CONTENT not working here?