# How can I add an image into a PDF file

Tags: android, itext

I've tried numerous example code online but I can't figure out how to implement an image into an `Itext` PDF file.  Could someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Which iText version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This is written based on ItextPdf java 
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("sample1.pdf"));
            document.open();
            Image img = Image.getInstance("arvind-rai.png");
            document.add(new Paragraph("Sample 1: This is simple image demo."));
            document.add(img);
            document.close();


// Follow below link if you want solution in android 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15742238/5380981
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for that check is out ,

```
Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("sample2.pdf"));
        document.open();
        Image img = Image.getInstance("arvind-rai.png");
        img.setAbsolutePosition(450f, 10f);
        document.add(img);
        document.close();
```